# How to get global.window.localStorage inside getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have some component which get props with data and render it data. In my `getServerSideProps` function I need to get data from `localStorage`, but I can't do it because of `window` is `undefined`.

I tried using `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` but it's still not working. What's wrong with my code?

```
const MainComponent = ({serverResponseData}) => {
  // ... some code
  console.log(serverResponseData))
  // ... some code
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  let filterId = []

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    filterId = global.window?.localStorage.getItem('filterId') || '';
  }

  // ...some code, and filterId variable still empty array
  const scoresRes = await fetchData('scores',{filterId});

  return {
    props: {scoresRes}
  };
}
```

I'm also tried use useEffect, but got error

> React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "getServerSideProps" that
> is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook
> function.

Comment: As i know getServerSideProps is a function of NextJS that runs on server side instead of client's browser - so it's a normal behaviour. You can try useEffect hook directly inside MainComponent as it only runs on client side.

Comment: @Deniz, yeah but I'm need get some params in getServerSideProps for send it in request, and it params saved in localStorage. Is there a way to send this param from MainComponent to getServerSideProps and make resend request ?

Comment: If the data you want to work with is not sensitive, you can put it in queryString and then you can access it in getServerSideProps. Otherwise you have to do it on the client-side (useEffect is the best option as i know).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

> If you export a function called `getServerSideProps` (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by `getServerSideProps`.

Localstorage is only available on the **client side** and you are trying to access it in a server side only function , you can use something like

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
// your code 
  const id = query.id;
    const getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
    console.log(getData)
}
```

Please review [this article](https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-server-client-code/) to get more information on running client side only code.

Another approach would be to use a [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) where the hello3 component would contain the code accessing local storage.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) only trigger on the server-side and it won't be available on the client-side

> getServerSideProps only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser.

If you want to have that storage logic, I'd suggest you use cookies instead. Not like localStorage, cookies are available on both server-side and client-side.

You can modify your logic like below with cookies

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const filterId = context.req.cookies.filterId || ''; //get filterId from cookies

  // ...some code, and filterId variable still empty array
  const scoresRes = await fetchData('scores',{filterId});

  return {
    props: {scoresRes}
  };
}
```

Another possible approach is using [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) which is available on both sides

```
MainComponent.getInitialProps() {
  let filterId = []

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    filterId = global.window?.localStorage.getItem('filterId') || '';
  }

  // ...some code, and filterId variable still empty array
  const scoresRes = await fetchData('scores',{filterId});

  return scoresRes;
}
```